# How is the quotient of two ideals defined?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

If $A$ is a commutative ring and $I \subset A$ an ideal, then I do know what $A / I$ means. However my professor now sometimes writes $J / I$ where $J$ is not a ring, but an ideal $I \subset J \subset A$ (for example $\sqrt{I} / I$ ). I was wondering is this is common notation and if someone could tell me how the 'quotient' of two ideals is defined.

Comment: $I$ is still an ideal within $J$.

Comment: We only defined ideals of rings, so saying that $I$ is an ideal of $J$ would imply that $J$ is a ring (at least how we defined it).

Comment: @user9620780 If you invest a minute or two in thinking about how ring quotients are defined, you will find that it is completely independent of $A$ having an identity.  So the aversion to not necessarily being a ring with a capital $I$ is unfounded.

Comment: @user9620780 it is an easy exercise to show that any ideal is a non-unitary subring.

Comment: @rschwieb rings without identity were never really introduced to us, but it makes sense to me now, thx for the quick answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you like you can just say that $J/I$ is the quotient of abelian groups.

Beyond that, it still has a left and right $R$ bimodule structure inherited as a submodule of $A/I$.

It's also consistent to think of it as a quotient of a ring not necessarily having identity.

Even if $I$ isn't a ring with identity, nothing goes wrong. All of these nice structures are still there.

Comment: You seem to miss the fact that, when $J$ is an ideal, $I\subseteq J\subseteq A$, then $J/I$ is an ideal of $A/I$.

Comment: @egreg I didn’t realize I was in a contest to list all such properties, but ok.  The part I felt important to explain was how $J/I$ was justified, rather than its properties.  The balance was just incidental.

Answer (score 8):

Your teacher is thinking to the *ideal* $J/I$ of $A/I$.

There is a surjective ring homomorphism $A\to A/I$, sending $a$ to $a+I$. The image of $J$ under this homomorphism is an ideal of $A/I$ and it is quite naturally denoted $J/I$, because it consists of all elements of the form $x+I$, with $x\in J$. This assumes that $J\supseteq I$.

In the general case, if $J$ is any ideal of $A$, its image in $A/I$ under the canonical homomorphism above is $(J+I)/I$.

For instance, $\sqrt{I}/I$ is the nilradical of $A/I$. Indeed, if $x\in\sqrt{I}$, then $x^n\in I$ for some $n$, so the element $x+I$ is nilpotent in $A/I$. The converse is also clear.