# Two kinds of quotient of ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I am dealing with Commutative Algebra and I found two different (or not?) kinds of quotient of ideals.

> One of them, $I/J$, is explained at this topic: [How is the quotient of two ideals defined?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2966567/how-is-the-quotient-of-two-ideals-defined)

The other is the following:

> Being $A$ a ring and $I,J$ ideals of $A$, so we define the ideal quotient by $(I:J)=\{a\in A\, :\, aJ\subset I\}.$

Well, one is formed by elements of $A$, other, by classes. However, $(x+I)J\subset I$, so the classes are subsets of $(I:J)$... right?

Does exist any relation between these two quotients?

Many thanks for attention.

Comment: As far as I know, $(I:J)$ is not called a quotient, but usually  the *carrier* of $J$into $I$.

Comment: @Bernard, many thanks, could you take a look at here? http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~dmehrle/notes/old/alggeo/28QuotientIdeals.pdf

Comment: I see. Din't know thiis denomination (I'm accustomed to Bourbaki's and Grothendieck's notations). Ithink it's rather confusional for beginners – and *colon ideal* can't be translated in all languages.

Comment: *If* $x\in (I:J)$, *then* $(x+I)J\subseteq I$.

Comment: @Bernard https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_quotient

Comment: @Na'omi If you read carefully the linked M.SE thread can notice that $J/I$ is in fact a quotient ring, which is, in particular, an ideal in $A/I$. I would definitely don't call $J/I$ a quotient of ideals.

Comment: @Bernard Can it not be translated? Won't every language have a name for the symbol $:$? Also, what reference do you know which uses the term "carrier" of an ideal?

Comment: In French, we need two words (*deux points*) which would be a bit awkward. For the word ‘carrier’, I remmeber having met it in some papers when I was a student, but I can't remember which.

Comment: Sure the name would be awkward (and I do not deny it would be similarly awkward in Polish) but that doesn't mean literal translation is not possible :)

Comment: Thank you all for the useful comments, including about language.

Comment: @user26857, but $I$ or $J$ maybe are not rings, so could I call this of quotient ring? Thank you very much!

Comment: Every ideal is a (sub)ring (maybe without a unit). Once again, please read the answers in the linked thread.

Comment: @user26857, sorry, I think I do not explain well, I am dealing with commutative algebra, where all rings has unit. So, properly ideals are not rings in this case. However, the books still has the notion of $J/I$. But I think I understood what you mean. Maybe thinking on the quotient ring does not have the same context of the rest of discipline, but it is OK. Many thanks and sorry by the incovenient.

Comment: And how your book defines $J/I$?

Comment: @user26857, it does not define (is note of classes), for it I am confused... It only uses, and in sense of $x+I$, $x\in J$. I'll ask the professor for the definition he uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, $(I:J)$ is the maximal ideal $K$ satisfying $KJ\subseteq I$. 
Putting it into the quotient ring $A/I$, we get
$$(I:J)/I \cdot (I+J)/I =0$$
(where $0$ is the trivial ideal $I/I$ of $A/I$) 
and $(I:J)$ is maximal with this property.

Comment: Thank you, it's interesting.